# Do many proxies still deny caching of urls with a question mark?

Tags: http, caching, proxy

I'm optimizing a website by moving static assets to another domain and server, which will respond with long `Expires` headers. I'd like to be able to add a version token to the urls to force clients to download a new version, eg. `http://static.example.com/foo.min.js?v=123`.

**Is it still problematic to use a query string in static asset urls?** Earlier I've seen [tutorials telling to avoid query strings in static assets](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/), because some proxies would not cache these urls.

Is this still the case?

Should I use another naming scheme, maybe with some url rewriting on the web server? Eg. `http://static.example.com/123/foo.min.js`. (To keep the deployment process simple, I don't want to actually have to create a `123` directory.)

I know this makes quite a simple `mod_rewrite` (or similar) rule, but I'd like to keep my static asset web server dead simple, and replaceable, that's why I'd prefer a query string based approach in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>[After a bit more digging...] Yes, it seems that at least Squid still does this. So rewriting it is.</del>

Thanks Julian, it really seems the default config [has changed four years ago, with Squid 2.7 and 3.1](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent).

Comment: On one of Squid developers tells me this was changed four years ago.